# Solr / Sunspot - determine indexing language at runtime, dynamically choose analyzers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, full-text-search, solr, sunspot

I would like to use Solr + Sunspot to index a bilingual FR-EN site. The issue: model Post can be written both in French or in English. I can determine at runtime what is the language, but I also need Solr to index the model accordingly.

EG: For French models, I would need a French stemmer,

```
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
```

What are my options? Can I change Solr analyzers at runtime? Can I make a set of analyzers  for each language?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a great question, and a feature that's being discussed for inclusion in Sunspot.

Sunspot uses dynamic field naming conventions to set up its schema. For example, here are two existing definitions for text fields:

```
<dynamicField name="*_text" stored="false" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_texts" stored="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

These correspond to the `fieldType name="text"` defined earlier in the schema.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

You could add a similar definition for the different languages you'd like to index (as Mauricio also mentions), and then set up some new `dynamicField` definitions to use them.

#### 1. A `fieldType` definition for a French text field

```
<fieldType name="text_fr" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

#### 2. A `dynamicField` definition for the French text field

```
<dynamicField name="*_text_fr" stored="false" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_texts_fr" stored="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

#### 3. Using the French text field in Sunspot

The latest Sunspot 1.2 (not quite released — use 1.2.rc4) supports an `:as` option which lets you specify the field name.

```
searchable do
  text :description, :as => 'description_text_fr'
end
```

---

Like I said, this is something I'm thinking of adding to Sunspot 1.3 or 1.4. Personally, I'd like to see something like `:lang => :en` on a text field definition to choose the appropriate field definition. Do feel free to chime in on the Sunspot mailing list with your thoughts!

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, Nick :) However, using :as, how can i determine at runtime the type of field? (Can I use a lambda?)

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head, you'd have to check the source. If it doesn't, perhaps it should :)

Comment: Nick, how about using the multicore feature? As discussed here: http://outoftime.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20339/tickets/17-multiple-rails-app-using-a-single-solr-server

Comment: Shouldn't `type="text"` be `type="text_fr"` at "2. A dynamicField definition for the French text field" ?

Comment: @NickZadrozny even after 5 years, this answer is so valuable, thank you, you have no idea how happy I am to be able to perform stemmed searches in both italian and english in my documents :)

Comment: @Cec: so glad to hear that! S.O. answers by their nature can get kind of stale over the years, happy to hear this one is beating the average :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't say anything about Sunspot, but in pure Solr I'd create separate field types in your Solr schema (one fieldType for French, another for English), then create one field for English content (using the English fieldType) and another field for French content (using the French fieldType).

Since you know which language to use at runtime, you'd just pick one field or the other to run your searches and get results.